# Qualtrics - Is it possible to have functionality such autofill value based on previous value

Tags: autofill, qualtrics

I am new to Qualtrics and trying to figure it out how to autofill value based on previous value. I have looked up online but I have not succesful so far.

I have tried using Drill Down, but it does not autofill the column I still need to select the data. The scenario is for example, I enter unique id and below will automatically fill the name that has the unique id (see reference attached).[When select the ID, name of member would appear automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE50G.png)

Therefore, is it possible to do autofill in Qualtrics? I also have looked at Embedded Data and Passing information but not understand how it works.

Embedded data: https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-flow/standard-elements/embedded-data/

Passing information: https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-flow/standard-elements/passing-information-through-query-strings/

Comment: This question isn't really suited to Stackoverflow since it isn't directly about coding. The [Qualtrics Community](https://community.qualtrics.com) would be a better place. The answer is that it is possible using JavaScript. The function [ddAutoComplete](https://qualtricswiki.tgibbons.com/doku.php?id=ddautocomplete) does it.

Comment: Thanks, Gibbons for your help. Will try to ask the Qualtrics Community. Thanks